# 2 identical DependencyProperties on different pages

Tags: vb.net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, dependency-properties

I have a DependencyProperty called H1Property declared as shown below:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly H1Property As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("H1", GetType(String), GetType(Button), Nothing)
Public Property H1() As String
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(H1Property), String)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        SetValue(H1Property, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

At page1 I use it to assign a value to the button with custom template (e.g. template1, need to use same template on different pages, so it is stored in App.xaml). I also have another page in the project (page2) with the same H1Property in code-behind. When I dynamically add buttons with template1 on page1, it works fine, but when I navigate to page2, then go back to page1 and generate controls again, values in new buttons are empty. No errors, just empty fields.

What is the problem? Is there a way to declare DependencyProperty only once and then use it on different pages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a module that stores the common state and reference it in the pages

```
Public Module CommonState
    Public ReadOnly H1Property As DependencyProperty = _
        DependencyProperty.Register("H1", GetType(String), GetType(Button), Nothing)
End Module
```

On both pages

```
Public Property H1() As String
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(CommonState.H1Property), String)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        SetValue(CommonState.H1Property, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

In case you need the `H1Property` on the pages itself, you can wrap it into a property

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property H1Property() As DependencyProperty
   Get
      Return CommonState.H1Property
   End Get
End Property
```